# How to ignore materialize.css classes that are impacting primeng autocomplete?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, materialize, primeng

I am using primeng autocomplete (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete), bootstrap 4, and materializecss (http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html). I see that the only css that is really messing up the page is the autocomplete form box.

How can I stop materialize.css from messing up the style of the autocomplete component?

```
<form>
    <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="texts" [suggestions]="results" (completeMethod)="search($event)" [multiple]="true">
        <ng-template let-value pTemplate="selectedItem">
            <span style="font-size:18px">>{{value}}<</span>
        </ng-template>
    </p-autoComplete>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `browser-default` class to `p-autoComplete` element in order to ignore Materialize CSS in that case :

```
    <p-autoComplete inputStyleClass="browser-default" [(ngModel)]="texts" [suggestions]="results" (completeMethod)="search($event)" [multiple]="true">
        <ng-template let-value pTemplate="selectedItem">
            <span style="font-size:18px">>{{value}}<</span>
        </ng-template>
    </p-autoComplete>
```

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kD9GPQrry1LeFPsg6drd?p=preview)